# Python function to add binary columns to a pyspark df

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe `productusage` like :

| featureSk | PersonNumber |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1001 |
| B | 1001 |
| C | 1003 |
| C | 1004 |
| A | 1002 |
| B | 1005 |

I need to create a python function that has a list of person numbers as input and outputs a dateframe which has the values of `featureSk` column from `productusage` as columns. Basically there should be a column for each `featureSk` value and a 0 on a row if the `PersonNumber` doesnt exist in `productusage` and a 1 if it does exist in `productusage`

output should be a pandas dataframe like :

| PersonNumber | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1002 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1003 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

This is what I tried

```
def add_featureSk_to_dataframe(Person_list):
    Person_list = pd.DataFrame(Person_list)
    df = productusage
    unique_values = df[featureSk].unique()
    for value in unique_vaues:
      for person in Persons_list:
        df = df.withColumn(value, lambda person: 1 if person in Persons_list else 0)
    return df
person_test = [1001,1002,1003]
add_featureSk_to_dataframe(person_test)
```

Getting an error that featureSk is not defined even though the `productusage` is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def person_has_product(person_list):
    df = dfPersonQuery
    
    #Distinct product names
    products = df.select("featureSk").distinct()
    
    # Filter df for the required persons
    filtered_df = df.filter(col("personnumber").isin(person_list))

    # Perform crosstab on the person and product columns
    cross_tab_result = filtered_df.crosstab("personnumber", "featureSk").withColumnRenamed("personnumber_featureSk", "personnumber")
    # Iterate through the distinct products in featureSk column
    
    for column in cross_tab_result.drop("personnumber").columns:
        cross_tab_result = cross_tab_result.withColumn(column,when(col(column) > 0, 1).otherwise(0))

    return print(cross_tab_result.toPandas())
    
person_lst =[1001, 1002, 1003]
person_has_product(person_lst)
`
```

Comment: with help from @Andrej Kesely I have satisfied my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.crosstab`:

```py
out = pd.crosstab(df["PersonNumber"], df["featureSk"])

vals = [1001, 1002, 1003]

# with .reindex the missing vals are filled with 0
print(out.reindex(vals, fill_value=0))
```

Prints:

```
featureSk     A  B  C
PersonNumber         
1001          1  1  0
1002          1  0  0
1003          0  0  1
```

Comment: i need the function to work for an input list and not the pre-existing `productusage` personnumber

Comment: @Bert2 You can reindex/filter the output dataframe. I've updated my answer.

Comment: tried this. Problem still persists. says name "PersonNumber" is not defined

Comment: yes. the column exists.

Comment: @Bert2 Make sure there are no trailing spaces in the column name, also the case must be the same. As you stated in your question, you have two columns `PersonNumber` and `featureSk`

Comment: productusage is a pyspark dataframe. Will that cause an issue?

Comment: @Bert2 Could be. I don't have any experience with pyspark. You should probably edit your question and put that information there. Also put correct tags into your question. When you mention *dataframe* in Python context, everyone assumes you have `pandas` dataframe.

Comment: Working on databricks and therefore I am dealing with pyspark as well as pandas. The output dataframe needs to be a pandas dataframe in my case. Will update the tags, thanks